# Traceback (most recent call last) np.int8

Tags: python, opencv

I am shown with the given below problem: let me help how to solve.Thanks.

```
#Traceback (most recent call last):
#File "C:/Users/Admin/PycharmProjects/frec/part3.py", line 15, in 
#<module>
#Training_Data.append(np.asarray(images, dtype=np.uint8))
#File "C:\Users\Admin\.virtualenvs\frec\lib\site- 
#packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 538, in asarray
#return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
#TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a 
#number, 
#not 'NoneType'
```

nothing i have no idea how to find solution for it.

```
for i, files in enumerate(onlyfiles):
image_path = data_path + onlyfiles[i]
images = cv2.imread(image_path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
Training_Data.append(np.asarray(images, dtype=np.uint8))
Labels.append(i)
```

no idea.

Answer (score 0):

Probably,  the index's in the for loop.
2 issues.

1) no indentation of the body of the for loop.  The code as you have shown does not loop over the last 4 lines.  You need to indent these if you want them to be evaluated in the context of the loop.  Otherwise, your indexes, i and files are not defined.

```
for i, files in enumerate(onlyfiles):
    image_path = data_path + onlyfiles[i]
    images = cv2.imread(image_path, 
    cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    Training_Data.append(np.asarray(images,dtype=np.uint8))
    Labels.append(i)
```

2) You have 2 indexes, but use only 1.  Is `files` defined, or is it extraneous?  If it is extra, what you think is going into `i`, may actually be going into `files`.

In any case,  there is a variable that has been assigned a None value. You need to find out which one.

Comment: one is used for data the other is used for indexing. both are in use.

Comment: The files object does not appear in the body of your loop. Check again!